# Castellar font family on mobile chrome not setting

Tags: css, fonts

I recently changed the font-family of some text on my site to Castellar and it worked without problem on desktop until I noticed that it doesn't work on mobile and android shows the default font family. As if android chrome only accepts a few fonts. For example I found out that android chrome has no problem with Times new Romans.

Is it something I am doing wrong and is there something I can do about it?

UPDATE: This is the code I used:

```
<h1 class="h3 text-center" style="font-family:Castellar;">Dietary 
Fibre Intake and Reduced Risk of Coronary Heart Disease</h1>
```

And this is the url: http://labreports.info/pub/37/Dietary+Fibre+Intake+and+Reduced+Risk+of+Coronary+Heart+Disease

Try the page here: https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly and you can see that the font is different on mobile devices that PC.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I updated the question with the code an actual URL.

Comment: So is this what you want it to look like? http://imgur.com/gEZMN7T

Comment: It is not Castellar. View the page on a PC, that's Castellar.